# Set Cache-Control header for 301 redirects

Tags: php, redirect

I need to set the Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate only for 301 redirects with function:

```
function cache_control_handle_redirects() {

    if ( $status == 301          ||          $status == 308 ) {



     header ( "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" );


}

}
add_filter( 'wp_redirect_status', 'cache_control_handle_redirects', 10, 2 );
```

Does wp_redirect_status can handle Cache-Control header as well?

Comment: 301 and 308 are for *permanent* redirects. Not wanting to cache them implies they are not permanent, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first problem is that `$status` is not coming from anywhere. In a filter you need to accept arguments in your callback function. If the number of arguments you're accepting is greater than 1 then you also need to specify that number as the 4th argument to `add_filter()`.

You also need to return that value or the modified value. In this case if you don't do that then you're removing the status code from all redirects.

With these issues corrected your code will look like this:

```
function cache_control_handle_redirects( $status, $location ) {
    if ( $status == 301 || $status == 308 ) {
        header ( "Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" );
    }

    return $status;
}
add_filter( 'wp_redirect_status', 'cache_control_handle_redirects', 10, 2 );
```

That should do what you want.

There is a conceptual issue with this, in that filters should probably only be used for modifying values and not performing actions like this. That said, I don't see any alternatives other than [plugging](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) the `wp_redirect()` function to incorporate this functionality and it *should* work regardless.